# Keycloak invalid redirect URL - grafana

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, grafana, saml

I'm trying to **integrate keycloak with Grafana dashboards** but when I'm trying to login on grafana via keycloak I'm receiving invalid redirect URL.

[keycloack grafana settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Suhbw.png)

I've added the bellow config on **grafana.ini**

```
[auth.generic_oauth]
enabled = true
scopes = openid email profile
name = Keycloak
tls_skip_verify_insecure = true
allow_sign_up = true
client_id = grafana
client_secret = ba342011-3705-483c-8e04-7f95be561cd5
auth_url = http://192.168.101.223:8080/auth/realms/grafana/protocol/openid-connect/auth
token_url = http://192.168.101.223:8080/auth/realms/grafana/protocol/openid-connect/token
api_url = http://192.168.101.223:8080/auth/realms/grafana/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
```

---

[url_redirect invalid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMHDY.png)

Everytime when I am trying to login, this is redirecting to localhost:3000, but I didn't set up this on the keycloak.
I found many cases on the google but no luck for my side.

```
2021-11-02 12:43:06,838 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-6) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=grafana, clientId=grafana, userId=null, ipAddress=172.18.212.8, error=invalid_redirect_uri, redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/login/generic_oauth
```

I want to mention that the Grafana and Keycloak are installed on the same server..

Answer (score 2):

You have missed the doc https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/generic-oauth/:

> You may have to set the root_url option of [server] for the callback URL to be correct. For example in case you are serving Grafana behind a proxy.

You didn't set root URL so incorrect redirect URL is generated `http://localhost:3000/login/generic_oauth` instead of domain/IP:port, which you have used in the browser. Fix that and it should be fine.

Comment: On grafana.ini I've already added the root_url option like : root_url = http://0.0.0.0:3000 but didn't fix the problem

Comment: @CiocoiuPetrisor root url config must match url in your browser, e.g. `http://192.168.101.223:3000` - read URL where you see `url_redirect invalid` error and you will see which redirect URL was generated by Grafana - that must be that value, which you have configured in the Keycloak client configuration - redirect url

Comment: I changed the config on keycloak : root_url: http://192.168.197.220:3000/login/generic_oauth ; * Valid Redirect URIs : *  , but I receive the same redirect : http://localhost:3000/login/generic_oauth?state=oiL_9MI_gfmFcU-ZVvJO4s0Swfd6lZrpc9VM5EkN4X0%3D&session_state=98c721dc-bb10-44a6-91bb-38b0b1a02269&code=dc05f1d3-80a5-45bb-82c0-04342af6df9a.98c721dc-bb10-44a6-91bb-38b0b1a02269.c9dda734-4963-46f3-be65-fd2211e5b332

Comment: Please read doc https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/configuration/#root_url you are still wrong value, in your case it should be `root_url = http:// 192.168.197.220:3000/`. It it root URL of Grafana config, not a Keycloak root url client config.

Comment: ok.. i got it now..still having one issue regarding the "error getting email address" - t=2021-11-03T05:21:59-0400 lvl=eror msg="Error getting email address" logger=oauth.generic_oauth url=http://192.168.197.220:8080/auth/realms/grafana/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo/emails error="{\"error\":\"RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://192.168.197.220:8080/auth/realms/grafana/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo/emails\"}"

Comment: Sorry, this is not a chat. You have had a problem with redirect url and that's solved. You should to accept answer and then eventually open new question with reproducible example about another issue. I recommend to read doc https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/generic-oauth/ first. root url config was mentioned there, so there will be also solution for many other related problems.

Comment: Thank you so much for you patience and your solutions